# My calibration chart (p-chart for quality control) is a straight line. What does it mean?

Tags: r, charts, controls

I have this assignment to do and I am unsure as to what is the problem here, if there is any. Attached are the images of the plots generated on Rstudio.

I did the following script:

```
library(qcc)
## Control Charts

#Phase 1
View(Amostra_Procon)
require(qcc)
attach(Amostra_Procon)
windows()
qcc(Amostra_Procon$NaoAtendidas[Trial], sizes=Size[Trial], type="p")
qcc(Amostra_Procon$NaoAtendidas[Trial], sizes=Size[Trial], type="p", newdata=NaoAtendidas[!Trial], newsizes=Size[!Trial])
#Phase2
qcc(Amostra_Procon$NaoAtendidas[Trial], sizes=Size[Trial], type="p", newdata=NaoAtendidas[!Trial], newsizes=Size[!Trial])
```

The result of the phase one is the calibration data. And the result of the phase 2, is the newdata. Here is a picture of the calibration and the newdata:

[image]

The thing is that my calibration data is a straight line, and that's not what I expected, because the data is not uniform like that. Or am I interpreting these wrong? Could someone help me interpret these, please?

I ask because thats not how I see it working for that rstudios' orangejuice sample. And my table has thousands of lines, so it doesnt make sense.

Anyway. Thank you

I am doing the control charts (p-chart) of a data base and all of my variables are qualitative.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is your question about your R syntax or about interpreting the plot? If you want to change what your graph looks like, please include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). If you need help interpreting your graph, please post on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the welcome hehe. I think the plot is right, so Ill check over there. Thank you